# is it possible to assign a value to a field added with EventListener symfony in $builder symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, addeventlistener

I would like to know if it is possible to automatically assign values ​​to added fields of type:

- datetime
- entity

Thanks for your help

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $user = $options['user'];      // entity User
    $player = $options['player'];  // entity Player
    $today = new DateTime('now');  

    $builder

        ->add('fieldA')
        ->add('fieldB')
        ->add('fieldC');

    $builder

        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($user, $player, $today) {

            $form = $event->getForm(); 
            $datas = $event->getData(); 

            $form->add('today');
            $form->add('user');
            $form->add('player');
            //dd($form);  ok = 3 fields added

            $datas['dateDuJour'] = $today;
            $datas['user'] = $user;
            $datas['player'] = $player;
            //dd($datas); ok = 3 assigned values

            $form->setData($datas); 
            question 1 :  how to insert the data in the form
            question 2 :  pb from entity (object) to string 
            //dd($form, $datas);
}


public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class'   => Evaluation::class,
        'user'         => null,
        'player'       => null
    ]);
}
```

}

I thought about inserting the 3 fields with the type = hidden and using Data Transformer

I do not know what is the best practice?

if you have a concrete example

Comment: Could you explain you case more precisely, I mean what do you want to do with data? Why "PRE_SUBMIT"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can see, you have some form and you want to plug 3 data to the form on submit.

Depending on your database configuration, you can do 3 different way:

The best one is to use the mapping

Your evaluation have those 3 fields:

- date
- user
- player

Then just add them to the original builder as hidden field whith default value what you have:

```
$builder->add('token', HiddenType::class, [
    'data' => $today,
])->add('user', HiddenType::class, [
    'data' => $user,
])->add('player', HiddenType::class, [
    'data' => $player,
]);
```

As they are hidden, the security check will not autorise users to change those value plus thoise fields will be hiddent
It require those three fields exist in your entity

Second one is to use unmapped hidden field. Same a previous, but add `` 'mapped'` => false `` . Then you in your controller, you will have the value and use them as needed.

The third one is to not use them in your form (my favorite) but in your controller

```
    public function addEvaluation(Request $request, EvaluationManager $evaluationManager): Response
    {
        $evaluation = new Evaluation();
        $form = $this->createForm(EvaluationType::class, $evaluation);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $evaluation->setTime(new DateTime('now'))
                       ->setUser($user)
                       ->setPlayer($player);
            $evaluationManager->save($evaluation);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('evaluation_add');
        }
        return $this->render('/evaluation_add.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your very clear explanations. I had opted for solution 3 but I did not know what was the best practice?
I'm looking to explore addEventlistener but it seems like this is mainly used for modifying a form and adding a value and not an entity for example. I didn't know : "he security check will not autorise users to change those value plus thoise fields will be hiddent It require those three fields exist in your entity" thank you

Comment: The best practice is the solution 3: formEventListener would not be usefull here, and you want give as few as possible possible information in client side. So it is what is more secure, more easy to implement, and most understandable.